# jQuery custom vertically scrolling UL bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
     <li class="entry">
       <div class="t_time">16:40</div>
       <div class="t_label">Some text</div>
     </li>
     <li class="entry">
       <div class="t_time">16:40</div>
       <div class="t_label">Some text</div>
     </li>
     <li class="entry">
       <div class="t_time">16:40</div>
       <div class="t_label">Some text</div>
     </li>
     <li class="entry">
       <div class="t_time">16:40</div>
       <div class="t_label">Some text</div>
     </li>
         <li class="entry">
       <div class="t_time">16:40</div>
       <div class="t_label">Some text</div>
     </li>
      <li class="entry">
       <div class="t_time">16:40</div>
       <div class="t_label">Some text</div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and this JS to make it slide vertically:

```
    function scroller(){


        $('#wrapper ul').animate(
        { 
            top: '-=' + $('#wrapper ul li:last').height()
        },
        3000,
        'linear',
        function(){
            var offset = $('#wrapper ul li:last').offset().top;                
            console.log(offset);
            if( offset <= 640){
                 $('#wrapper ul').css("top", 0);
                $('#wrapper ul li:last').after($('#wrapper ul li:first').detach());
            }
        }
    );
 }

 setInterval(scroller ,3000);
```

Problem is, when I try to get rid of the list type bullets, some bug happens and it won't work anymore!

here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3v4Ab/2/

If you add a line in the CSS that will remove the list-style such as: `#wrapper ul{list-style:none;}` it won't work anymore! any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just [experimented with it](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/3v4Ab/3/), (I changed a few settings for the timeout in my fiddle).  It seems if the list elements do not have an assigned height, it will cause your issue in jQuery animate.

add this to the stylesheet and it will work just fine:

```
#wrapper ul li {height:50px; list-style:none;}
```

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean :) Thanks a lot! I will find a workaround ;)